# How to resolve Springboot build error in STS - CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml, spring-tool-suite, build-error, sts

Here is my POM.xml file and Errors I got in STS as below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ducat.springboot.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>Ideas</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <name>Ideas Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    
    <!-- spring boot parent dependency jar -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        
    </properties>
    
    
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
         </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>

        <finalName>Ideas App</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.8.0 -> org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-incremental:jar:1.1 -> org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1 -> org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1 -> org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1 -> backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1: ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:pom:3.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:pom:3.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target    pom.xml              /Ideas   line 13   Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)            pom.xml              /Ideas   line 13   Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Answer (score 0):

It would be generally helpful if you provide the stack trace as a code snippet to make it more readable.

It looks like the root cause is as follows:

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

You should find posts here on StackOverflow or on the web that explain how to configure the JVM you are using to execute Maven. :)